# When We say a diagram in a category is a functor, then how do we treat the category? Do we take it as 2-catgegory?

Tags: category-theory, functors, enriched-category-theory

In a Category $\textbf{C}$, we say that an $\cal{I}$-diagram in a category is a functor $F: \cal{I} \to \textbf{C}$. In fact, Any object A can be viewed as a diagram by defining a functor $F: \cal{I} \to A$.
How would we treat the category then? for example, if I have $\cal{I}$ shaped diagrams in category $\textbf{C}$ would I be able to define the morphisms(natural transformations) between those diagrams(functors)? In other words, should I treat my category as a 2-category now? Would it be the right way? if yes then can I treat every category as a 2-category?

Edit: I am not only talking about cone, which is a constant diagram over $F$. I am also thinking about the natural transformation between diagrams of the same sort that is $F:D \to \textbf{C}$ and $F': D \to \textbf{C}$. In other words category of diagrams (same size and shape).
let's say I have triangle-shaped diagrams I am talking about morphisms between them. is there a formal category for that? and how will I treat my original category $\textbf{C}$ now? As a 2-category?

Comment: Could you phrase your question more clearly? If the question is about morphisms between $I$-diagrams in $\mathcal{C}$, then yes they are just natural transformations of functors. In other words, you are working in the category of functors $ \operatorname{Fun}(I,\mathcal{C})$...

Comment: In particular, a natural transformation $\Delta_c \Rightarrow F$ represents a cone over $F$, where $\Delta_c$ is the constant diagram in $c \in \mathcal{C}$. If that's what you are interested in.

Comment: @MPos yes, but the cone is a constant diagram over $F$. I am thinking about the natural transformation between diagrams of same sort that is $F:D \to C$ and $F': D \to C$. In other words category of diagrams (same size and shape).
let's say I have triangle-shaped diagrams I am talking about morphisms between them. is there a formal category for that?

Comment: This seems like reindexing a diagram in $\mathcal{C}$. If you wanted to make a category out of these, I can see just needing a definition of morphisms $\widetilde{\alpha}: F\to F'$, where say $\alpha:\cal{I}\to\cal{I}$ is a functor taking $dom(F)$ to $dom(F')$ such that $F'\circ \alpha = F$ or something similar.

Comment: @RabiaSagheer I gave the cone as an example. As mentioned $Fun(I,\mathcal{C})$ perfectly captures morphisms between arbitrary $I$-diagrams, i.e. between arbitrary functors $F,F': I\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$.

Comment: @MPos so every category can be taken as a 2-category? because diagrams in it can be taken as functors. This is a good example showing why the category is called abstract nonsense.

Comment: @RabiaSagheer that was not my point. To define functors into $\mathcal{C}$ you are viewing $\mathcal{C}$ as an ordinary 1-category. If you like, all these notions sit inside of the 2-category of categories $\operatorname{Cat}$ but that has nothing to do with $\mathcal{C}$ being more than a 1-category.

Comment: Of course one can view any 1-category as a strict 2-category by adding only the identity 2-morphisms, but that's beside the point.